# I installed a program with pip and now I don't know how to start it

Tags: software-installation

I installed a program with pip (https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-20.04/) and now I don't know how to start it. Or is the program always on? The installed program is this: http://www.bonvinlab.org/pdb-tools/

I know that in Linux program can be started with "./program name" command, but is there other ways? I am using Windows subsystems for Linux 2 and Ubuntu. So, I can only see terminal.

Comment: Can you verify that the programs that you are trying to run, are located in the directory `/home/(uname)/.local/bin` where (uname) is replaced with your username, and also add the output of the command `echo $PATH` to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after the "How do I install" section of the website you linked, there is a "How do I use" section...

[image]

Comment: None of those commands work. Do I need to start the program before commands can be used?

Error is: command not found

Answer (score 0):

yes these tools are command line tools. The functions are described [here](http://www.bonvinlab.org/pdb-tools/#list-of-tools)

Here an example:

```
Usage:
    python pdb_b.py -<bfactor> <pdb file>

Example:
    python pdb_b.py -10.0 1CTF.pdb
```

This explains how the pdb_b tools is being used. By installing via pip, you install python code, which has to be executed with python interpreter. Thus the "python" before the tool name (which is a small python program that expects parameters.

You have to execute those commands in the terminal - so no GUI for these tools.

Comment: I didn't write "python" to the start of the command. Ok. That is how it probably should work. I tried for example "python pdb_fetch.py 1brs" and "python3 pdb_fetch.py 1brs". They don't work. I think I need to use "python3" because I have version 3. It says that "python" not found. If I use "python3", is says that "can't open file "pdb_fetch.py". Don't know that his means.